# Not able to log in to my associated account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

I have a SO account and have associated askubuntu account with it.

I log in using Livejournal's OpenID as myOpenID is no longer supported officially but after logging into SO, am I able unable to log into AskUbuntu. Also, I'm not automatically logged in, even though that should be the default behavior.

**PS:** I had myOpenID previously, which was there in my Ubuntu account, but the Livejournal login was not added to the Ubuntu login even though it was there in SO.

**Question :** How can I log back into my AskUbuntu account?

Below is the error page screenshot

[image: :]

Comment: Try logging in with other OpenID, then ask for accounts merge... that's what I would do in your place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : shall i add a fresh login to SO and try AU with that????

Comment: @ShadowWizard : same thing happened when i made a new login using `wordpress.com`!!!

Comment: Weird, need a dev/SE employee to take a look then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is connected to the merge you asked us to revert a few weeks back. It left a few things in a bit of an inconsistent state.

I've removed your AU profile entirely. Please log back into [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/login) using your LiveJournal ID - at that point, a new profile should be created for you, and you'll find the automatic login working properly.